# Does different personal information on ds160 and UK visa application pose problem?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

Let's say I was wrongly advised and ignorantly chose married on my ds160 for USA visa application. I was traditionally engaged but not legally. The USA  visa application was denied under 214b. Some years later, I intend to apply for a study visa in the UK and my visa application states single as marital status which is the correct representation since the previous relationship didn't work out and no divorce as it was not legally binding.

Will this new information affect my visa application with the UK?

Comment: It's not really a big deal, marital status keeps on changing from time to time. Just don't forget to list your US refusal in your UK visa application.

Comment: Okay. I understand. It becomes a major problem if one lies about the refusal on the application.

Comment: A 214(b) denial is common, meaning you either didn’t sufficiently demonstrate that you qualified for the visa you applied for and/or didn’t overcome the presumption of immigrant intent https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-denials.html Mis-stating your marital status could be a problem in some circumstances eg if the ECO decided that it was deliberate in order to improve the strength of your ties to home and thus your chances of getting the visa

Comment: @traveller even if this "mis-stating" was on USA visa application?  How can this be corrected?

Comment: @Gary Will I’m just saying that you should be careful how you explain the reason for your US visa refusal in your UK visa application. Do not lie, but equally the UK may not see it favourably if you say for example ‘I was refused because I stated I was married when I wasn’t’. If you were applying for another US visa you’d possibly need to be more concerned, but you’re not.

Comment: Oh many thanks. I understand your point more clearly. The USA refusal was not as a result of my marital status.